# How can we write a a query without using temporary tables in detail explanation in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need the deep explanation for the queries that are not using the temporary tables in SQL Server 2008 and without using the cursors.

Thanks,
Vara Prasad.M

Comment: What do you mean?  Reasons to not use temporary tables?  To use temporary tables vs variable tables?

Comment: without using the temporary table i have to traverse all the rows for a given condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a variable table with an identity and iterate through it (also known as RBAR [Row By Agonizing Row]) over using a cursor for several reasons:

1. Cursors lock the row - you can do
   more with a cursor such as moving
   backwards and updating but you're
   accessing your table
2. Using a variable table keeps the
   data in memory which is faster than
   using a physical table
3. Personally, I've been bitten too
   many times by forgetting to
   deallocate my cursor

Comment: without using the cursors is this is not possible?